# Make a span inside a cell table to go 100% height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can the span expand all the height?

http://jsfiddle.net/e27wut2p/

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="shrink"></th>
            <th class="shrink">AAA</th>
            <th class="shrink">BBB</th>
            <th class="shrink">CCC</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="label label-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></span></td>
            <td>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br>1<br></td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Tried tons of ways, none works. I am looking for a simple as possible solution as height: 100%.

Update: Expected result:

[image: expected result]

Comment: do you want vertically center icons?

Comment: ^ yes, inside the span label.

Comment: Are you trying to make the + icon larger?  it is an icon-font so you would have to use font-size to make it larger.  Not really sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution would be to stretch label with the help of absolute positioning relative to parent `td`:

```
td {
    position: relative;
}
td > span.label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
td > span.label:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e27wut2p/4/

In addition I also vertically alligned icon inside of label with `span.label:after` pseudo element.

Comment: `td > span.label {position: absolute; top: 5px; bottom: 5px; left: 50%; margin-left: -12px;}`

Answer (score 2):

For that kind of dynamic positioning, you really do need to use `position: absolute`.  You can supplement that with the margin trick. so that it doesn't have to fit 100% width (more like what you have in your image).  Is this closer to what you're looking for?

```
.table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
    position: relative;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td:first-child span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 2em;
    height: 85%;
}

.table > tbody > tr > td:first-child span.glyphicon {
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4LstLagu/